# Expand workspace to second monitor

Tags: 18.04, unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have 5x2 workspaces on my 18.04 with the 2 being horizontal (let's call them left and right). I'm using Unity. I would love to have a setup in which when I don't have second screen connected everything is normal and I'm able to switch left and right, but when the second monitor is connected I have left workspace on laptop screen and right workspace on horizontal screen and there would be no need to switch left and right, just up and down.

I've tried to search for it, but as being non-native speaker I couldn't find the right words so if the answer is here somewhere I'm sorry for bothering you!